# What book will help me understand Electric Circuits?

Tags: electric-circuits, resource-recommendations, electrical-resistance, capacitance, inductance

I have a problem having a clear picture when it comes to solving electrical circuits. I am talking about complex circuits which contain Inductors and capacitors . The methods introduced are clear to me but I am not sure if I really understand what I am actually Calculating. I would really be thankful if someone can resource me to a book where I can actually understand all the physics behind this stuff. I don't care about the methods, just physics!

Comment: University Physics by Young & Freedman. The chapters in the 20's take good care of that. https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B_FOFMzF0_0gbjNxakkzUkV4dzg/edit

Comment: It sounds like you want to visualize the quantities and relationships described by the math.  The book that first enabled me to visualize phase relationships, impedance and LC resonance in terms of electron flow was Electricity Made Simple, by Jacobwitz.  Out of print, but available used from Amazon.  I was seventeen at the time, and I later got a Master's in EE, but I still remember this book, and, in fact, just ordered a copy myself.

Comment: @Steeven  :You seem to be a big fan if that book,I too like that  :) and one can use these websites too for electronics.    https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-top-10-websites-electronics-communication-students-must-visit

Comment: Thanks for everyone ! I think these books will really be helpful for me !!

Answer (score 0):

To understand electric circuits on a deep level, you have to understand the microscopic and the macroscopic concepts. That will lead you to a point, where equations become natural and obvious. I highly recommend this MOOC part 1 and part 2.

https://www.edx.org/course/electricity-magnetism-part-1-ricex-phys102-1x-0

It has the advantage that it is

a) More easy to digest than a book.

b) Has exercises that are very useful to test yourself, if you really do understand a topic.

c) Is highly motivating.

It got me started in a deep understanding of that matter. But, how suitable this is for you, as any recommendation, depends on you level.